# Get player is not a function (Twitch)

Tags: twitch

I'm following the guide [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/embed/#interactive-frames-for-live-streams-and-vods) to embed the Twitch video player to a web page.

I'm copying the exact same code into an HTML file and running it, but it says "embed.getPlayer() is not a function". On top of that, the video player autoplays even though its not supposed to.

```
var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
    width: 854,
    height: 480,
    channel: "monstercat",
    layout: "video",
    autoplay: false
  });

  var player = embed.getPlayer();
  player.addEventListener(Twitch.Player.PLAY, function() {
    changeAdvertisementBanner();
  });
  player.play();
```

Comment: Just making sure, have you included the Twitch API script? `<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>`

Comment: Yep, I have @scramlo

Comment: Can you console.log(embed) and see if it is loading.

Comment: Not enough code to debug.  Please provide an MCVE.  Unable to tell if your scripts are correct, if you're accessing the javascript prematurely, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Interactive Players please check this doc :
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/#interactive-frames-for-live-streams-and-vods

If you use this way for creating the videoplayer then we can listen to all the changes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var options = {
        width: "255",
        height: "350",
        channel: "AnyChannelName!",
      };
      var player = new Twitch.Player("UniqueID", options); 

    player.addEventListener(Twitch.Player.READY, function () {
        alert("Player Is Ready");
    });

      player.addEventListener(Twitch.Player.PAUSE, function () {
        alert("PAUSE");
    });

       player.addEventListener(Twitch.Player.PLAY, function () {
        alert("PLAY");
    });
 </script>
```